# How to group an array of objects into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I need help regarding my problem as I couldn't wrap around my head with this problem.

so my JSON data looks like this.

```
let items = [
{
    "cargo": {
        "name": "Horse 1",
        "picture": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553284965-5dd8352ff1bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
    },
    "pickup_location": {
    "address": {
        "longitude": 120.96667,
        "latitude": 14.65,
        "name": "....",
        "full_address": "...."
    },
},
"dropoff_location": {
    "address": {
        "longitude": 120.86667,
        "latitude": 14.78333,
        "name": "....",
        "full_address": "...."
    }
}
},
{
    "cargo": {
        "name": "Horse 5",
        "picture": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qWeQrv1Foqo/maxresdefault.jpg"
    },
    "pickup_location": {
        "address": {
            "longitude": 120.96667,
            "latitude": 14.65,
            "name": "....",
            "full_address": "...."
        }
    },
    "dropoff_location": {
        "address": {
            "longitude": 120.86667,
            "latitude": 14.78333,
            "name": "....",
            "full_address": "...."
        }
    }
}

]
```

and I want to group the data by using the `latitude and longitude of the pickup and dropoff locations` and output them into something like this.

```
[
    {
        "cargo": [
            {
                "name": "Horse 1",
                "picture": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553284965-5dd8352ff1bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
            },
            {
                "name": "Horse 5",
                "picture": "htthttps://i.ytimg.com/vi/qWeQrv1Foqo/maxresdefault.jpg"
            },
        ]
        "pickup_location": {
            "address": {
                 "longitude": 120.96667,
                 "latitude": 14.65,
                 "name": "....",
                "full_address": "...."
            }
        },
        "dropoff_location": {
            "address": {
                "longitude": 120.86667,
                "latitude": 14.78333,
                "name": "....",
                "full_address": "...."
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I've attempted writing a reduce function but couldn't wrap my head around it. so please help me.

any answers are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will group similar item with unique details:

```
itemsGroup = {};
for(var item of items) {
    for(var key in item) {
        if(!itemsGroup[key]) {
            itemsGroup[key] = [];
            itemsGroup[key].push(item[key]);
        }
        else {
            var detailExists = itemsGroup[key].find(detail => JSON.stringify(detail) == JSON.stringify(item[key]));
            if(!detailExists) {
                itemsGroup[key].push(item[key]);
            }
        }
        
    }
}

console.log(itemsGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect pickup and dropoff to match every time.
It's probably best to create two objects to track them. I used a combination of lat+long for the key to keep it simple.

```
pickUps = {};
dropOffs = {};
items.forEach(function (item) {
  pickUpLoc = [
    item.pickup_location.address.longitude,
    item.pickup_location.address.latitude,
  ].join(":");
  dropOffLoc = [
    item.dropoff_location.address.longitude,
    item.dropoff_location.address.latitude,
  ].join(":");
  if (pickUps[pickUpLoc] != undefined) {
    pickUps[pickUpLoc].cargo.push(item.cargo);
  } else {
    pickUps[pickUpLoc] = {
      cargo: [item.cargo],
      address: item.pickup_location.address,
    };
  }
  if (dropOffs[dropOffLoc] != undefined) {
    dropOffs[dropOffLoc].cargo.push(item.cargo);
  } else {
    dropOffs[dropOffLoc] = {
      cargo: [item.cargo],
      address: item.dropoff_location.address,
    };
  }
});
```